# Kotlin with View Binding or Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose

I am about to start a new android project and came to know about Jetpack compose is now in a stable channel.
I have a few questions regarding it.

1. Is it stable enough to start a new project on it?
2. Is there a good community support and packages available?
3. Can I still use old packages like apollographql and other third party packages in it?

Answer (score 2):

Jetpack Compose is Completely Stable (Stable just means Stable, there's nothing like stable ENOUGH)

Yes the Stack Overflow Community Seems quite promising, but the Codelabs just kill it. Anything you want to learn, just visit the specific codelab they're dead awesome

Just check with the package maintainers to see if they have implemented libraries specific to Jetpack Compose.

Also, you could just make the project a hyrbid, combining the old view system and JC if support is not added yet. Check out the interoperability section in the [Compose Pathway](https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/compose).